Multi-Select Items in ListBox (PyWinAuto - UIA Backend)
following Situation:
I have a ListBox in an application I need to automate.

I can easily access Items with
        listBox = self.main_dlg.child_window(auto_id="AvailableRoleListBox", control_type="List")
        listBox.wait("ready", timeout=5)
        return listBox.item("Title of Item")

and select them with item.select().
I'm trying to select multiple Items from the list, followed by some actions for those items.
Sadly, whenever I select an Item, it immediately deselects any other selected item(s).
I guess one could relative position of each Item and simulate the mouse click while holding CTRL, although this might be an unreliable solution.
Are there any other (better) ways?
